# How to build a matrix from blocks

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, partitions

### Brief MWE

Given

```
Block[{mat, A, B, C, D, E, F, goal}, A = {{1, 2}, {7, 8}}; B = {{3, 4}, {9, 10}}; C = {{5, 6}, {11, 12}}; D = {{11, 22}, {77, 88}}; E = {{33, 44}, {99, 100}}; F = {{55, 66}, {110, 120}}; mat = {{A, B, C}, {D, E, F}}; goal = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {11, 22, 33, 44, 
55, 66}, {77, 88, 99, 100, 110, 120}}; Print@mat; Print@goal;]
```

How can I programatically create `goal` from `mat`?

**In other words, how can I combine block matrices to create a larger matrix?**

### Explanation and Current Progress

In the MWE, we see that `mat` and `goal` clearly share a similar structure:

[image]

we simply need to be able to remove the "interior" parentheses. However, the fundamental list structures are different.

I have attempted to solve this problem many ways, without success, typically involving `Flatten` or `FlattenAt`. My best effort has been

```
Block[{mat, A, B, C, D, E, F, goal}, A = {{1, 2}, {7, 8}}; B = {{3, 4}, {9, 10}}; C = {{5, 6}, {11, 12}}; D = {{11, 22}, {77, 88}}; E = {{33, 44}, {99,100}}; F = {{55, 66}, {110, 120}}; mat = {{A, B, C}, {D, E, F}};goal = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {11, 22, 33, 44,
55, 66}, {77, 88, 99, 100, 110, 120}};Partition[Flatten@mat, (Dimensions[mat][[2]])*(Dimensions[mat][[4]])]]
```

for which the crux of it is

```
Partition[Flatten@mat, (Dimensions[mat][[2]])*(Dimensions[mat][[4]])]
```

However, this doesn't produced the desired output, but rather, a scrambled matrix of the correct dimension:

[image]

Moreover, that "solution" seems poorly formed anyway, and not very robust to combining more general block matrices. What is a good way to accomplish this goal? In particular, I am only interested in combining a large number of (2x2) matrices into a large, square matrix, but I'm certain there should be a clean way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ArrayFlatten`

```
Block[{mat, A, B, C, D, E, F, goal}, A = {{1, 2}, {7, 8}}; 
 B = {{3, 4}, {9, 10}}; C = {{5, 6}, {11, 12}}; 
 D = {{11, 22}, {77, 88}}; E = {{33, 44}, {99, 100}}; 
 F = {{55, 66}, {110, 120}}; mat = {{A, B, C}, {D, E, F}}; 
 goal = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {11, 22, 33, 44, 
 55, 66}, {77, 88, 99, 100, 110, 120}}; 
Print@MatrixForm@mat;
Print@MatrixForm@goal;
Print@MatrixForm@ArrayFlatten[mat];
```

]

[image: array flat]

Comment: Thank you very much! Damn, I'm ashamed I didn't find that command from the `Flatten` documentation "see also." Sorry for wasting everyone's time...

Comment: @Steve no worries, I've suffered through the same pre-ArrayFlatten world as you. I think I accidentally selected it from the autocomplete to originally discover it!